# Can amphetamines suppress reactivity to scratch testing (for immunotherapy)?

Tags: immune-system, medications, allergen, amphetamine, allergen-immunotherapy

My understanding's that amphetamines are immunosuppressive... Theoretically, couldn't  these drugs result in false negatives?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE! To avoid having your question downvoted, put on hold, or closed, make sure to follow the guidelines for asking questions. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center > Asking](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Thanks!